# running a non mapreduce program in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra

I have a question.. I have a program write in Netbeans. the program read data from cassandra and write the result into it. My program is not MapReduce at all.I execute the program and make a .jar file from it. now, I want to know if I can execute it in Hadoop?
actually, I want to know can I run a non-MapReduce Program in Hadoop?

Comment: Why?  What advantage does Hadoop bring in that case?  Just the HDFS?

Comment: no, I don't know.. well I think it will speed up the program execution time.. So you mean this goal just happening with MapReduce framework in Hadoop?

Comment: Why will running Hadoop, a map reduce framework for executing massively parallelizable problems on a cluster, make a non-parallelized problem run faster than it does on a serial machine?  You don't understand what map reduce or Hadoop are for, then.

Answer (score 2):

You could architect this program to run on Hadoop v2 as a Yarn application. This would require re-architecting your application to fit the Yarn paradigm. An example of how to do this is given here: [Writing App Framework on Yarn](http://www.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/writing-app-framworks-for-hadoop-on-yarn)

This is not a simple exercise. Also, if you are interested in using Hadoop, I would consider simply re-writing your application to use HBase (another No-SQL Columnar database competitor to Cassandra) which is written specifically for Hadoop. It translates your query requests to MapReduce calls **automatically**.

Comment: Note: "Not a simple exercise".  Running on Hadoop by itself will do nothing for you.  Your problem has to be map-reduce-able.

Comment: "YARN stands for “Yet-Another-Resource-Negotiator”. It is a new framework that facilitates writing arbitrary distributed processing frameworks and applications."

Comment: "YARN is a generic platform for any form of distributed application to run on, while MR2 is one such distributed application that runs the MapReduce framework on top of YARN."  http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/10/mr2-and-yarn-briefly-explained/

Comment: Thank you Wes, I wasn't aware of YARN.  My point is that no framework will help you if your problem is not parallelizable.  I'll have to see what good YARN does in helping you write your parallelizable problems so they run their best.

Answer (score 0):

This question is ages long but has never been answered. Anyhow, two projects are looking into this issue:

Apache Slider (incubating): http://slider.incubator.apache.org/

and

Apache Myriad (incubating): http://myriad.incubator.apache.org/

Slider is mainly sponsored by Hortonworks while Myriad is a MapR / Mesosphere project with large assistance from PayPal.